# Server error with codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have two scripts with codeigniter in the same host, one of them is work fine. but the other one is show a server error. when I## Heading ## follow the problem I noticed the server error don't appear when I comment the line (In file CodeIgniter.php):

```
call_user_func_array(array(&$CI, $method), array_slice($URI->rsegments, 2));
```

### Update:

my `htaccess` file is:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php?|images|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1
```

Comment: what's the error. and we need more information to help

Comment: Script Is down and this Is the page error:

Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://****.com/test/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: why are you using CI reference and not using `get_instance()` method?

Comment: No, The line Is In the core CI Files, And the script work fine In Localhost

Comment: please update with your htaccess file

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php?|images|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

then if your ci is running under a directory , `for example "/foo"` replace with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /foo
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/index.php/$1 [L]
```